# Combine multiple highcharts in one page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts, dashboard

I am developing an asp.net project using Visual Studio, C#. I have created two charts using highcharts. Each one is on a single page. I want them to be displayed beside each other to form something like a dashboard. The HTML codes inside the aspx page is supposed to call the both scripts and I want to have them displayed on the same container.

**First Chart JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/ERP/DashboardCount3",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json:charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {

            /*
            //debugger
          
            //values = [0, 0, 0, 100, 0];
            var o = {};
            var data1 = [];
            // loop values count   i=0 
            var o = { name: 'Completed', y:values[i], sliced: true };

            data1[i] = o;
           // i++


*/

           //var values = [5, 85, 88, 100, 0];

            //var data1 = [];
            var values = json.DashboardCount3;
            var values2 = json.DashboardCount33;

            var dataSet = new Array;
            for( var i in values)
            {
                var o = { name: values2[i], y: values[i], sliced: true };//temp
                dataSet.push(o);

            }






            var completeCount = 5;
            var InProgressCount = 3;
            // Build the chart
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Projects Scope Of Work Status'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    point: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Count',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: dataSet
                }]
           });

        }


    })







});
```

**Second JS Chart Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/ERP/DashboardCount",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json:charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {

            debugger
            var values = json.DashboardCount;
            var completeCount = parseInt(values[0]);
            var InProgressCount = parseInt(values[1]);
            // Build the chart
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                   plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Projects Scope Of Work Status'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    point: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Count',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Completed',
                        y: completeCount,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'In Progress',
                        y: InProgressCount

                    }]
                }]
            });

        }


    })







});
```

**HTML created in aspx page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="projectTest.WebForm7" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
       <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="datatables/js/DashboardC.js"></script>
    <script src="datatables/js/Dashboard2.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        .chart {
        height: 200px;
    }

    .spacer {
        height: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"> 




        
    <p class="highcharts-description">  Description  </p>
    <div id="chart-A" class="chart">      <script src="datatables/js/DashboardC.js" ></script> </div>
    <div class="spacer"> </div>
    <div id="chart-B" class="chart">  </div>






    
     

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: chart A => Highcharts.chart('chart-A', {...
chart B => Highcharts.chart('chart-B', {...

Comment: Hi @Hanouf, Each chart needs to be rendered in a separate container, but you can wrap both chart containers with another element to use proper styling. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2uq9wjro/